# Change scene within the same window

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

How can I change the scene within the same window, rather than it opening a new window entirely.

Below is where the selectable options are added to a choicebox, with a listener at the end to "observe" when a selection is made, which, when clicked, changes the scene.

```
private void formulaOption2(){
list2.removeAll(list2);
String a = "Current Ratio";
String b = "Working Capital Ratio";
String c = "Debt to Equity Ratio";
String d = "Gross Profit Margin";
list2.addAll(a,b,c,d);
ChoiceBox2.getItems().addAll(list2);

//A LISTENER TO OBSERVE WHEN USER SELECTS ITEM
ChoiceBox2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( (v, oldValue, newValue) ->  {
    try {
        comboSelect2();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tab1FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}  );
}
```

Below is the code that loads the FXML file:

```
 public void comboSelect2() throws IOException {
if("Current Ratio".equals(ChoiceBox2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())){

   FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Tab2FXML.fxml"));
         Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
         Stage stage = new Stage();
         stage.setTitle("Current Ratio");
         stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
         stage.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the root of the current scene with the new root you want:

```
public void comboSelect2() throws IOException {
    if("Current Ratio".equals(ChoiceBox2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())){

       FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Tab2FXML.fxml"));
           Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
           ChoiceBox2.getScene().setRoot(root1);
    }
}
```